# performing case insensitive validation in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to the backend world and learning how to make an API with django rest framework. I went through some concepts already but I ran into some issues.

Context:
There are 4 resources. Store, Author, Book, Address. 1 CRUD endpoint for each of them except address. A store must have an address and a name. if the address exists, link it on creation, else create the address and create the store.

Problem:
I cannot seem to figure out this part "if the address exists, link it on creation, else create the address and create the store."

Here is the relevant info to the problem in hand

`views.py`

```py
class StoreViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def list(self, request):
        stores = Store.objects.prefetch_related('address')
        serializer = StoreSerializer(stores, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)


    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        pass

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = StoreSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

`models.py`

```py
class Address(models.Model):
    country = CountryField(null=False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    street_number = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    addition = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, default='')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['country', 'city', 'street', 'street_number', 'addition']
        constraints = [models.CheckConstraint(check=models.Q(street_number__lt=100000), name="street_number_lt_100000")]

class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    address = models.OneToOneField(Address, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    books = models.ManyToManyField(Book, blank=True)
```

`serializers.py`

```py
class AddressSerializer(CountryFieldMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = '__all__'

class StoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    address = AddressSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Store
        fields = '__all__'
```

I tried adding this to the create method

```py
def create(self, validated_data):
    address_data = validated_data.pop('address')
    address_instance, _ = Address.objects.get_or_create(**address_data)
        
    store = Store.objects.create(address=address_instance, **validated_data)
    return store
```

EDIT:
my new serializer looks like this.

```
class StoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    address = AddressSerializer()

    def validate_address(self, value):
        # Perform case-insensitive validation for the address fields
        country = value.get('country', '').lower()
        city = value.get('city', '').lower()
        street = value.get('street', '').lower()
        street_number = value.get('street_number', '')
        addition = value.get('addition', '').lower()

        existing_address = Address.objects.filter(
            country__iexact=country,
            city__iexact=city,
            street__iexact=street,
            street_number__iexact=street_number,
            addition__iexact=addition,
        ).first()

        if existing_address:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Address already exists.")

        return value

    def is_valid(self, raise_exception=False):
        # Call the custom validation explicitly
        self.validate_address(self.initial_data.get('address', {}))
        
        return super().is_valid(raise_exception)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        address_data = validated_data.pop('address')
        address_instance, _ = Address.objects.get_or_create(**address_data)

        store = Store.objects.create(address=address_instance, **validated_data)
        return store

    class Meta:
        model = Store
        fields = '__all__'
```

I found that the problem was coming from the view where it called is_valid()